# Postfix not sending mail but receive only in CWS

Tags: centos, postfix, centos7

I am using a centos web panel and not able to send mail from postfix. But I can receive mail. I am getting the following error in a log file when I try to send mail from Roundcube

```
postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-03-06 16:38:17 UTC; 59s ago
  Process: 27736 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27749 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27747 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27745 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 27823 (master)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─27823 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─27824 pickup -l -t fifo -u -o content_filter= -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
           ├─27825 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
           ├─27828 proxymap -t unix -u
           ├─27830 trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u
           ├─27838 smtp -t unix -u
           ├─27840 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u
           ├─27844 smtp -t unix -u
           ├─27845 smtp -t unix -u
           ├─27846 smtp -t unix -u
           ├─27847 smtp -t unix -u
           ├─28004 showq -t unix -u
           ├─28216 smtpd -n submission -t inet -u -o stress= -s 2 -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
           ├─28217 anvil -l -t unix -u
           ├─28314 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -o stress= -s 2 -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:127.0.0.1:10024 -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
           ├─28316 cleanup -z -t unix -u
           ├─28317 smtp -n smtp-amavis -t unix -u -c -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200 -o disable_dns_lookups=yes -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
           └─28357 smtpd -n 127.0.0.1:10025 -t inet -u -c -o content_filter= -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0 -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001 -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000 -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks -o smtpd_helo_required=no -o smtpd_client_restrictions= -o smtpd_restriction_classes= -o disable_vrfy_command=no -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes

Mar 06 16:39:09 server.templatemaza.com postfix/smtpd[28314]: disconnect from localhost[::1]
Mar 06 16:39:11 server.templatemaza.com postfix/smtpd[28216]: warning: unknown[94.102.49.198]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Mar 06 16:39:11 server.templatemaza.com postfix/smtpd[28216]: disconnect from unknown[94.102.49.198]
Mar 06 16:39:14 server.templatemaza.com postfix/smtpd[28357]: connect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
Mar 06 16:39:14 server.templatemaza.com postfix/smtpd[28357]: ECC5310C4DF5: client=unknown[127.0.0.1]
Mar 06 16:39:14 server.templatemaza.com postfix/cleanup[28316]: ECC5310C4DF5: message-id=<4eb35fcb2ac9247dbab11b264e5320d3@templatemaza.com>
Mar 06 16:39:14 server.templatemaza.com postfix/qmgr[27825]: ECC5310C4DF5: from=, size=1366, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 06 16:39:14 server.templatemaza.com postfix/smtpd[28357]: disconnect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
Mar 06 16:39:14 server.templatemaza.com postfix/smtp[28317]: 9474110C4DF3: to=, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=5.4, delays=0.06/0.03/0/5.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as ECC5310C4DF5)
Mar 06 16:39:14 server.templatemaza.com postfix/qmgr[27825]: 9474110C4DF3: removed
```

The output of `postconf -n`

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
anvil_rate_time_unit = 3600s
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_
id & sleep 5
delay_warning_time = 4
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 2048000000
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 204800000
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = templatemaza
myhostname = server.templatemaza.com
mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_vacation.cf
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtp_tls_session_cache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 500
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unknown_client
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_required = yes
```

An output of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:0a:94:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.148.0.3/32 brd 10.148.0.3 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 1982sec preferred_lft 1982sec
    inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fe94:3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include relevant details such as which version of CentOS and Postfix you’re running.  For Postfix-related questions, the output of `postconf -n` is really useful as that shows how your configuration differs from the default settings.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Thank you for your interest. I have edited the question and I am using centOs 7. But I don't know how to check the version of postfix.

Comment: *delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4003:c09::1b]:25: Network is unreachable* indicates that Postfix can’t connect to `2607:f8b0:4003:c09::1b`. The default behaviour for Postfix is to attempt to use IPv4 if IPv6 fails (and vice-versa). It looks like that’s not happening in this case. However, from the output of `postconf -n`, I can see that `inet_protocols` is correctly set to `all` and `smtp_address_preference` hasn’t been changed from its default – so I can’t think what else could be causing the problem.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan So now what to do next?

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan No problem!. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Your IPv6 connectivity is broken. Contact your service provider for further information.

Comment: @michaelHampton thank you for your reply. I am using the Google cloud. Can I fix it by cloud settings?

Comment: Google Compute VMs don't (currently) have IPv6 connectivity. How did your instance get configured? Show the output of `ip a`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Please check the output of `ip a` in question

Comment: You don't have an IPv6 address at all! You can just safely ignore the message.

Comment: @MichaelHampton But I am not able to send an email. What to do?

Comment: Check your mail server logs to find out why. There isn't anything in the question to indicate that you are even having a problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have updated question with a new log. please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90676/discussion-between-jay-padaliya-and-michael-hampton).